# Access current position in Spotify Api

Tags: api, spotify

Since Spotify changed around their API recently, their documentation isn't the greatest. Their docs say to access the current position in a song, access `models.player.position' which logs as being undefined.

Has anyone had better luck getting the song position with the new Spotify API?

Comment: Have you tried with models.player.load('position').done(function(p){ /* p.position stores the current position */});  ?

Comment: Facepalm. Thanks buddy. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position` is an attribute that needs to be fetched through the `load` function:

```js
models.player.load('position')
  .done(
    function(p){
      /* p.position stores the current position */
    });
```