# Spotify Api, position property bug

Tags: javascript, api, properties, position, spotify

I found a tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168334/access-current-position-in-spotify-api) explaining how to get the current position of the current track playing using Spotify API.

The code works just fine, except that there is a serious bug and seems beyond my control:
If a song is playing while I am starting my app/reloading it, the position variable wont update. The *load* function will return the position the song was on the moment the app was loaded/reloaded and **not** the current position of the song!

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by the position attribute on the player object not being updated directly, so you need to wait until the track object has been updated. You can listen for the track change using the addEventListener method on the player.

I've created [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/thelinmichael/0435aa817817d415079d) showing an example on how you can do this.

API reference: http://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-player.html

Hope this helps!