# Access current position in Spotify Api returns error

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to access the current position of a song playing in Spotify and according to the documentation, the solution given in this Q&A should work: [Access current position in Spotify Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168334/access-current-position-in-spotify-api)

Code:

```
models.player.load('position')
 .done(
   function(p){
    /* p.position stores the current position */
 });
```

Unfortunately, it throws the following error back:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number core.desktop.js:2
f.executeRequest.onSuccess core.desktop.js:2
```

Any explanations / tips to what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:**
I played a bit around, and it seems that I the same error in two other situations:

- From the models.player.addEventListener(...). It does not give the error right away, but as soon as I skip a track or searches in it, the error appears again.
- From the tutorial app itself when trying the get-the-current-playing-track page. Unfortunately I cannot see the actual code, but they claim to do a models.player.load('track').

All in all; it just seems like a bug :-(

Comment: Is your app setup for api v1, with the proper require statement at the top of the .js file, referenced in the manifest?

Comment: @Thomas: I think so; the doc has been slightly wanty on this subject. In my manifest I have declared
 "Dependencies": {
   "api": "1.10.2",
   "views": "1.18.1"
  },

and my require is stated like:
  require(['$api/models', '$views/image#Image'], function(models, Image) { ... });

Comment: Perhaps I should note that I am running the Linux-client (v0.9.4.183.g644e24e0) - not that I would expect it to make any difference. At least I hope it does not ;)

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  If you want to try other sample code to show it's an issue with the linux client, you could give my open source app a try :).  https://github.com/matelich/album-radio

Comment: Briefly tried your app, but it does not seem to work. It will not accept Drag 'n' Drop of my playlist. Sometimes your drop area lights up green. Sometimes not. But the cursor is always a stop sign.

Comment: Annoying.  I've only ever tried it on Windows, though the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect changing your manifest to have these dependencies should do it.

```
"Dependencies": {
  "api": "1.0.0",
  "views": "1.0.0"
},
```